# Bold a part of string in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to **BOLD** the part of a string in a `RichTextBox`. Basically it looks like this now:

```
Okl-24-220-20-10.56
```

The last digits 10.56 stands for the square meters of specific calculation. I want to have this **BOLD**. These numbers are then used to generate a barcode so I am hoping that by doing this, the barcode will also display this 10.56 as bold text.

I thought of using this in **summary `RichTextBox`**:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi");
sb.Append(@"\b amount: \b0 ");
sb.Append((txtAmount.Text);
sb.Append(@" \line ");
sb.Append(@"\b length: \b0 ");
sb.Append(txtLength.Text);
sb.Append(@" \line ");
sb.Append(@"\b width: \b0 ");
sb.Append(txtWidth.Text);
sb.Append(@" \line ");
sb.Append(@"\b total: \b0 ");
sb.Append(txtTotal.Text);
sb.Append(@" \line \line ");
sb.Append(@"}");

rtxtRequest.Rtf = sb.ToString();
```

[image: Desired output]

[[image: Desired output[2]]

Comment: The code you are using for the textbox doesn't match the output string you wrote first. Please be more clear: what do you want? The first string with just `10.56` in bold, or a whole summary?

Comment: Just 10.56 to be bold in summary richtextbox

Comment: `10.56` is `txtTotal.Text`?

Comment: @Truex If an answer solved your initial issue here, please mark it as answered. I can see it didn't solve the Barcode text font, but that wasn't this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712521/bold-a-part-of-string-in-generated-barcode

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what the code you show for generating the RTF is for (since it's not shown on your screenshot), but I guess you can do something like:

```
var rtf = $@"{{\rtf1\ansi Okl-{txtAmount.Text}-{txtLength.Text}-{txtWidth.Text}-\b {txtTotal.Text}\b0}}";
displayRichTextBox.Rtf = rtf;
```

I just tested it just in case:

[image]

Is this what you want?

Note that depending on the barcode generation technique, it may or may not look bold there.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are the same length, or you can easily parse them, `RichTextBox` allows you to select a portion of a line and change its style.

First call [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s(v=vs.110).aspx), then use [`SelectionFont`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont(v=vs.110).aspx) to make the fragment bold. The MSDN examples should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Sure, I understand, but the text within the richtextbox is being imported from all other textboxes when entered by user (amount, length, width, total), then it all displays in summary richtextbox. How do I manage to adjust the settings of total only?

Comment: @Truex you should really post a sample of the expected output, so that we can see what the RichTextBox should look like at the end.

Comment: @ s.m. just added samples, please check attached, thank you