# Bold a part of string in generated barcode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, barcode

I am generating a barcode as an image. The barcode consists of few different values, such as amount, length, width and m2. These numbers are displaying below the barcode as a summary of all user entries. Is there a way to either bold or underline the m2 (square meters) in the summary under the barcode? Please see below sample of what is needed:

[image: Sample outcome]

Here's the code I use to generate the barcode:

```
private void generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String barcode = summary.Text;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 40, 150);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
            Font ofont = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 20);
            PointF point = new PointF (2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush White = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.FillRectangle(White, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", ofont, black, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                box4.Image = bitmap;
                box4.Height = bitmap.Height;
                box4.Width = bitmap.Width;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: `Bitmap`, `Font` and `SolidBrush` all implement `IDisposable` so you should probably wrap them in a `using` statement.

Comment: No, this is not possible. The Letters are __part__ of the barcode font and can't be bolded separately from the bars. But you can always__hack__ (urgh)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constructor of `Font` that accepts a font style ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
```

The problem comes in determining what part of the text should be bold which means you will have to split the text up at a certain point, and ascertain the offset of the bold text

Since the font you're using ([`IDAutomationHC39M`](http://www.dafont.com/idautomationhc39m.font)), renders the bar code also, this won't work unless you find a different font that will allow you to render the bars separately to the text. This leaves you with a few options.

1. Separate fonts
2. Don't make the text you want to bold
3. Make it stand out in a different way, colour the text in a different colour that will make it stand out / draw a line under it / etc

Comment: Yes, exactly, however adding FontStyle.Bold will also bold the barcode itself causing it being useless and not readable by scanner.

Comment: @Truex If you want only part of the text to be bold your going to have to split it out from the main drawing section, i.e. another `g.DrawString`

Comment: Please see added sample above, I have added the FontStyle.Bold and it caused the barcode to get thicker as well as font

Comment: @weston - Oh right I see, [`IDAutomationHC39M`](http://www.dafont.com/idautomationhc39m.font) is a font that renders the bars... Truex, I think you might need to use a different font that renders the bars separately

Comment: @Truex - For example - [this font](http://www.dafont.com/3of9-barcode.font) appears to render it separately, I can't remember how much support winforms gives for custom fonts

Comment: Oh, I see, the font does include the lines! Sorry @Truex, I didn't spot that you were the OP and know what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

## If this was just text

You need to break the text up into 2 parts,

```
string barcode1; //the normal bit
string barcode2; //the bold/underlined bit

Font ofont = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 20);
Font ofontBold = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Then render text in 3 stages, measuring the offset of each previous part:

```
graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode1, ofont, black, point);

var point2 = new PointF(point.X + graphics.MeasureString("*" + barcode1, ofont).Width, point.Y);
graphics.DrawString(barcode2, ofontBold, black, point2);

var point3 = new PointF(point2.X + graphics.MeasureString(barcode2, ofontBold).Width, point2.Y);
graphics.DrawString("*", ofont, black, point3);
```

## However the font includes the lines

So I think the best you can do is to draw an underline using the same string measuring techniques:

```
string barcode1; //the normal bit
string barcode2; //the underlined bit

var lineStartX = point.X + graphics.MeasureString("*" + barcode1, ofont).Width;
var lineWidth = graphics.MeasureString(barcode2).Width;
```